# Need help with this step in asymptotically solving a PDE

Tags: discrete-mathematics, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I am reading a paper with the following Kolmogorov forward equation or Fokker-Planck equation:
$$\frac{\partial\phi(x,t)}{\partial t}=[\frac{a(x)}{N}\phi(x,t)]_{xx}-[\frac{b(x)}{N}\phi(x,t)]_x$$
The subscripts with $x$ denote derivatives with respect to $x$. For $N$ large they seek an asymptotic solution of the form:
$$\phi(x,t)\sim e^{NS(x,t)}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{A_m(x,t)N^{-m+1/2}}$$
Upon inserting this into the first equation, they obtain:
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{N^{-m+3/2}[aS_x^2-S_t]A_m+N^{-m+1/2}[(aS_{xx}+2a_xS_x-bS_x)A_m+2aS_x(A_m)_x-(A_m)_t]+N^{-m-1/2}[(aA_{m-1})_{xx}-(bA_{m-1})_x]\sim0}$$
I need help with this because I do not understand how they obtained the $A_{m-1}$ terms in the last equation.

Oh, and also, here is the link to the paper:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0025556475900103

Comment: Have you tried yourself substituting the asymptotic ansatz into the equation and see what it gives?